# multipass mount options

Tags: 20.04, mount, multipass

When mounting a local directory inside a multipass instance...

```
flydutch@led:~$ multipass mount /media/TEST multipass-test:/opt/TEST
```

...it is mounted with `nodev` flag:

```
ubuntu@multipass-test:~$ mount
...
:/media/TEST on /opt/TEST fuse.sshfs (rw,nosuid,nodev,relatime,user_id=0,group_id=0,allow_other)
```

Is it possible to specify the `dev` flag option?

Remount the directory inside the instance doesn't work:

```
ubuntu@multipass-test:~$ sudo mount -o remount,dev /opt/TEST
/bin/sh: 1: sshfs: not found
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`fuse.sshfs` driver do not support `dev` option.
it's not possible to enable this option.